# How to add multiple attributes in InstallData Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.9

Please specify how to add multiple attributes in single InstallData script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the above solution using patches. It's working and I used the same methodology using InstallData/UpgradeData.php according to my requirement.

Please check my answer
This will save the data in the database in table customer_entity_varchar and attributes in eav_attribute.
Check the code:

```
<?php
namespace CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class UpgradeData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

private $eavConfig;

private $attributeResource;

private $customerSetupFactory;

/**
* @var AttributeSetFactory
*/
protected $attributeSetFactory;

protected $moduleDataSetup;


public function __construct(
\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
\Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource,
CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
) {
$this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
$this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
$this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
$this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
$this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
$this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;

}

public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
//$customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "phonenumber");

$customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
$attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

$attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
$attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


/** attribute_1 */
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
Customer::ENTITY,
'phonenumber',
[
'type' => 'varchar',
'label' => 'Phone Number',
'input' => 'text',
'required' => true,
'visible' => true,
'user_defined' => true,
'sort_order' => 991,
'position' => 991,
'system' => 0,

]
);

$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
Customer::ENTITY,
'phonenumber'
);

$attribute->addData(
[
'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer',
'customer_account_create',
'customer_account_edit']
]
);

$attribute->save();

/** attribute_2 */
$customerSetup->addAttribute(
Customer::ENTITY,
'gstnumber',
[
'type' => 'varchar',
'label' => 'GST Number',
'input' => 'text',
'required' => true,
'visible' => true,
'user_defined' => true,
'sort_order' => 992,
'position' => 992,
'system' => 0,
]
);

$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
Customer::ENTITY,
'gstnumber'
);

$attribute->addData(
[
'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer',
'customer_account_create',
'customer_account_edit']
]
);

$attribute->save();


}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 uses Data scripts to add attributes.
In folder Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data add a .php file (eg: AddCustomerAttributes)

The following will add a few customer attributes.
After adding this bin/magento setup:upgrade command is required.

There will be an entry added to patch_list datatable, if the script file was executed correctly and also the attributes in the eav attribute table of course.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCustomerAttributes implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    protected $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        /** attribute_1 */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_1',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Attribute One',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'default' => 0,
                'system' => 0
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_1'
        );

        $attribute->addData(
            [
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
            ]
        );

        $attribute->save();

        /** attribute_2 */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_2',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Attribute Two',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Options',
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'default' => 0,
                'system' => 0
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_2'
        );

        $attribute->addData(
            [
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
            ]
        );

        $attribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need help with anything on this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me check and will confirm if it is working fine or not :)

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me that if it is a convenient approach to add custom attributes using a data patch? Can you provide the solution in the installdata.php file?